# Group Multiple Tables in LINQ json result

Tags: c#, linq

How to show 10 recipes with categories like this:

```
   {"CategoryName":"CategoryName1",

   .
   .
   .
   10 recipe item
   },
   {"CategoryName":"CategoryName2",

   10 recipe item
   }
```

My code:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------

     var infoQuery = (from r in db.tbRecipe
                             join s in db.tbCategory
                                 on r.CategoryID equals s.ID
                             group new { r, s } by new { r.ID,r.CaloryValue,r.CategoryID,r.CoockTime,r.ImageList,r.Name,r.VideoURL , s.CategoryName } 
                             into grp 
                             select new
                             {
                                 grp.Key.CategoryName,
                                 grp.Key.ID,
                                 grp.Key.ImageList,
                                 grp.Key.Name,
                                 grp.Key.CaloryValue,
                                 grp.Key.CoockTime,
                             }).Take(10);


            return Json(infoQuery.ToList());

    -----------------------------------------------------------
      my result:        

    [
{
    "CategoryName": "ایرانی",
    "ID": 1,
    "ImageList": null,
    "Name": "باقالی پلو",
    "CaloryValue": "200",
    "CoockTime": 20
},
{
    "CategoryName": "فوت وفن",
    "ID": 2,
    "ImageList": null,
    "Name": "میگو",
    "CaloryValue": "100",
    "CoockTime": 10
},
{
    "CategoryName": "بین المللی",
    "ID": 3,
    "ImageList": null,
    "Name": "باقالی پلو",
    "CaloryValue": "200",
    "CoockTime": 20
},
{
    "CategoryName": "بین المللی",
    "ID": 4,
    "ImageList": null,
    "Name": "میگو",
    "CaloryValue": "100",
    "CoockTime": 10
},
{
    "CategoryName": "دریایی",
    "ID": 5,
    "ImageList": null,
    "Name": "باقالی پلو",
    "CaloryValue": "200",
    "CoockTime": 20
},
{
    "CategoryName": "دریایی",
    "ID": 6,
    "ImageList": null,
    "Name": "میگو",
    "CaloryValue": "100",
    "CoockTime": 10
}
 ]
```

Comment: What do your classes look like? And which type of LINQ is this? (Or: what is `db`?)

Comment: i'm using entity frame work db first , my database is sql , i have a model diagram(.edmx)

Comment: you did not understand my question did you? do i have to change it?

Comment: You want your recipes to be grouped by their category?

Comment: yes , and i want to show 10 recipe for each category

Comment: I understand your question but I need to see the classes (for the navigation properties) and the type of data access. I assume it's Entity Framework but you always should mention it, including its version.

Answer (score 0):

I improved your query and this should do the trick for you.

```
 var infoQuery = (from r in db.tbRecipe
                         join s in db.tbCategory
                             on r.CategoryID equals s.ID
                         group new { r, s } by new { r.ID,r.CaloryValue,r.CategoryID,r.CoockTime,r.ImageList,r.Name,r.VideoURL , s.CategoryName } 
                         into grp 
                         select new
                         {
                             grp.Key.CategoryName,
                             grp.Key.ID,
                             grp.Key.ImageList,
                             grp.Key.Name,
                             grp.Key.CaloryValue,
                             grp.Key.CoockTime,
                         }).GroupBy(g => g.CategoryName, g => g)
                           .Select(g => g.Take(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get your result as follows:

```
var lstCategory = new List<Category> { new Category { Id=1}, new Category {Id=2 }, new Category { Id = 3 } };

var lstRecipe = new List<Recipe> { new Recipe { Id=1,Name="C1",CatId=1}, new Recipe { Id = 2, Name = "C2", CatId = 2 },
        new Recipe { Id =3, Name = "C3", CatId = 2 },new Recipe { Id =3, Name = "C4", CatId = 3 },new Recipe { Id=1,Name="C5",CatId=1} };

var result = (from c in lstRecipe
                 join s in lstCategory
                 on c.CatId equals s.Id
                 group c by c.CatId
                 into g
                 let o = g.Take(10)
                 select o);

var lstItems = new List<DtoModel>();

    foreach(var r in result)
    {
        var item = new DtoModel { Recipet = new List<RecipetDto>() };
        item.CategoryName = r.First().CatId.ToString();
        foreach(var s in r)
        {
            item.Recipet.Add(new RecipetDto
            {
                Id=s.Id,
                Name=s.Name
            });
        }
        lstItems.Add(item);
    }
```

and then get json data as follows:

```
string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstItems, Formatting.Indented,
   new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
   });
```

your dto class:

```
class DtoModel
{
public string CategoryName { get; set; }
public List<RecipetDto> Recipet { get; set; }}
```